# Execute an event manually in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a class:

```
function x() 
{   
    this.initialize = function () { }         
    this.filterSelection = function (event, ui) { /* code */ }
}
```

I hook filterSelection method to other items through:

```
$(item).on("click", this, this.filterSelection );
```

When filterSelection is called, the **event.data** points to the instance of my class. 
Now I need to call filterSelection manually from within the initialize() method. 
How can I do this which setting the correct parameters?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: I'm guessing something like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/r5FT3/

Comment: Thanks adeneo. If you want to post that as an answer I will mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adeneo has answered this in the jsfiddle but its only as a comment leaving this question open.

```
this.filterSelection({data : this}, null);
```